# How to perform basic string handling in Progress

Tags: string, events, event-handling, openedge, progress-4gl

I want to put the whole alphabet in a string. For that, I need two variables, one containing the whole alphabet, the other containing a counter for the letters to be used, as follows:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE i AS INTEGER.
DEFINE VARIABLE Alphabet AS CHARACTER FORMAT "x(30)".
```

The logic I've found, does this as follows:

```
/* Main logic */
i = ASC("a").
REPEAT:
  APPLY CHR(i) TO Alphabet.
  IF CHR(i)="z" THEN LEAVE.
  i = i + 1.
END.
```

As I have experience in other programming languages, I would opt for another approach:

```
/* Main logic */
i = ASC("a").
REPEAT:
  Alphabet = Alphabet + CHR(i). /* This line is different */
  IF CHR(i)="z" THEN LEAVE.
  i = i + 1.
END.
```

Obviously my proposal is not working, but then I wanted to understand why, and I had a look at [an official URL, explaining the `APPLY` statement](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvref%2Fapply-statement.html%23), stating the following:

> APPLY statement
>
> > Applies an event to a widget or procedure.
> > Syntax
> >
> > > APPLY event [ TO widget-phrase ]

Now I'm lost: what is the relationship between chars in a string, and events (I understand an event as a button-click or something)? (I fear I'm completely misunderstanding this whole concept)

**Edit, after some more research:**

In the meantime I've understood that I can make the whole thing work, as follows:

```
/* Main logic */
i = ASC("a").
REPEAT:
  Alphabet = Alphabet + CHR(i). /* This line is different */
  IF CHR(i)="z" THEN LEAVE.
  i = i + 1.
END.
Alphabet:SCREEN-VALUE = Alphabet.
```

This, however, only shows me that "normal" string-handling is possible in Progress, it does not yet explain the whole `event`-thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables in Progress actually have two parts: the normal variable part and the displayed part. When you assign a value to a variable it is only assigned to the variable part. If you want to assign a value only to the displayed part you assign it to yourvariable:screen-value. If you want to get the displayed value to the variable value you can say

```
assign yourvariable.
```

And if you want to display the variable value you say

```
display yourvariable.
```

Some keywords and functions apply to the displayed nature of variables. The example you have that uses APPLY does not work for me, but I guess the intent there was to simulate key-presses on a displayed variable - hence APPLY-ing each letter. Seems like a strange way of doing it.

Your last code sample makes most sense, though I would modify the last line as follows:

```
i = ASC("a").
REPEAT:
  Alphabet = Alphabet + CHR(i). /* This line is different */
  IF CHR(i)="z" THEN LEAVE.
  i = i + 1.
END.
display Alphabet.
```

Note that if you do not need to show a variable's value on a screen there is no reason to call DISPLAY.